# Sub Menu decentralizado - de acordo com navegador, Nao sei onde estou errando

Tags: javascript, css, html5, menu, css-hover

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
/*Sub-Menu*/

.menu.superior .nivel-dois, .menu.superior .nivel-dois, .menu.superior .nivel-um li:hover .nivel-dois{ display: contents; position:absolute; }

.pagina-login .menu.superior, .pagina-busca .menu.superior, .pagina-carrinho .menu.superior{ display: relative; }

.menu li.com-filho{
 position:inherit;
}
.menu.superior .nivel-dois{
display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:103px;
    text-align:center;
    left:auto;
    margin-left:-35px;
    min-width:auto;
    width:140px;
    /*background:#fff;*/

}
.menu.superior .nivel-dois a{
font-weight:bold;
    color:#564119;
    margin-top:3px;
    background:#fff;
    width:157px;
    margin-left:-35px;
    
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px ;
       -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px ;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px ;
           box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px ;
}
.menu .nivel-dois, .menu .nivel-tres, .menu.lateral .nivel-um>li>a{
background:transparent;
}
.todas-menu-1{
background:transparent;
margin-left:-15px !important;
}

/*Fim do SubMenu */
```

Comment: Usando position, px, float, etc... É chato e quase nunca vai ficar bom. Aconselho você usar Flexbox

Comment: vou tenta usar agora, pra ver

Comment: Só lembrando que Flex só funciona do IE10 para frente e mesmo assim apresentã vários tipos de bug https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Nada...não estou conseguindo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo o seu erro é esse `margin` desnecessário!

Veja na imagem que removendo ele fica tudo alinhado!

Então na classe `.menu.superior .nivel-dois` retire o `margin-left: -35px`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: valeuuuuuuuuuu , quase que me mato aqui, valeuuu , algo simples, que me passei

Comment: Isso ai garoto, as vezes os Browser entendem o CSS de forma diferente, por isso é bom testar. Boa sorte!

Comment: obrigado, valeu mesmo.